# Why is this 5 body network constantly rotating?

Tags: graph, data-visualization, physics, vis.js, graph-visualization

I could not understand why this simple network configuration keeps spinning around node 2, except after some nudges around [30s mark in this screen cast](https://i.imgur.com/NeQn2Sg.mp4), after which it restarts spinning. The setup uses visjs network module with [forceatlas2 resolver](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0098679).

My options param for the Network constructor is as follows:

```
get options(): Options {
return (
  this.optionS || {
    nodes: {
      shape: 'dot',
      size: 30,
      font: {
        size: 32
      },
      borderWidth: 2,
      shadow: true
    },
    edges: {
      width: 2,
      shadow: true,
      smooth: {
        enabled: true,
        roundness: 0.5,
        type: 'cubicBezier',
        forceDirection: 'vertical'
      }
    },
    physics: {
      forceAtlas2Based: {
        avoidOverlap: 0.25,
        gravitationalConstant: -95,
        centralGravity: 0.01,
        springLength: 100,
        springConstant: 0.19,
        nodeDistance: 175,
        damping: 0.11
      },
      minVelocity: 0.75,
      solver: 'forceAtlas2Based'
    }
  }
);
}
```

The host angular component provides these 5 nodes:

```
const nodes = new DataSet([
  { id: 1, label: 'Node 1' },
  { id: 2, label: 'Node 2' },
  { id: 3, label: 'Node 3' },
  { id: 4, label: 'Node 4' },
  { id: 5, label: 'Node 5' }
]);

const edges = new DataSet([
  { from: 1, to: 3 },
  { from: 1, to: 2 },
  { from: 2, to: 4 },
  { from: 2, to: 5 }
]);
this.graphData = { nodes, edges };
```

The network directive simply instantiates the Network as follows:

```
this.network = new Network(
    this.el.nativeElement,
    this.graphData,
    this.options
  );
```

Any insight into why this sort of perennial motion happens would be appreciated. I need to understand what factors to keep in mind for generating 'stable' nodes so that users do not have to keep chasing nodes/edges to click/interact with.

Comment: Here's a 31s second clip with a different zoom to better see all 5 nodes: https://i.imgur.com/x12ocSm.mp4

Answer (score 3):

Increase minVelocity or damping to stop this.

The way you configured it the physics actually never stops moving the nodes around. Nodes 1, 2, 4 and 5 are kept in star arrangement by central gravity. Node 3 then pushes node 1 away but since everything's connected it ends up moving all of the nodes. Thanks to the edge between node 1 and 3 the force is stronger in one direction than the other. This then applies never ending force on the whole arrangement which ends up slowly spinning around node 2.

Faster spinner: [image]